# Review your banning procedure

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes, post-ban

I was banned at Stack Overflow from asking questions in November 2012. After some time that ban was lifted. After that I was more conscious while asking questions. I asked 4 questions after that. No upvotes but 2 down votes for a post. I knew very well they are well formed and they aren't off-topic.

See the below four questions

- [Phonegap - SAP BSP Application - fails to load with Login pop-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193316/phonegap-sap-bsp-application-fails-to-load-with-login-pop-up)
- [MongoConnectionException - Failed to connect to: localhost:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215833/mongoconnectionexception-failed-to-connect-to-localhost27017)
- [How to return JSON data from php MongoCursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232261/how-to-return-json-data-from-php-mongocursor)
- [What can be done with Mongo Aggregation / Performance of Mongo Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255816/what-can-be-done-with-mongo-aggregation-performance-of-mango-aggregation)

They are really new technologies. I didn't get valid or useful answers from Stack Overflow. But I found solutions from other forums, where employees are answering. I put those answers
in my Stack Overflow posts for others.

It should take some time for others to sense it's usage. Because they are new technologies and they are not used by many like HTML, Jquery. So the attention for those posts is lower and the probability for getting upvotes is also less.

Again I am banned by your system. I suspect the last four posts might be taken by your system. If so, is there any fault in my side?

Based on the information above I have the following feature requests:

1. Show the reason for ban.

   > **Update:** Instead of showing this link http://goo.gl/C1Kwu for ban. Show
   >   valid reason for ban.
2. Get compulsory comments for downvotes from users having less than 5000 points.

   > **Update:** increase 125 reputation to 5000 for down votes, if you fear about invalid comments
3. If possible try to rethink the banning algorithm with my above scenario.

Comment: Regarding point 2 - See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: @ChrisF instead of show it as option, make it mandatory to register down vote for users having less then 5000 points. I have 400 points and i am having ability to put down vote. What if open 1500 posts and put down vote as time pass.

Comment: The mandatory aspect is discussed in the answers to the question - it would cause more problems that it would solve. People would just add "aksdlkfhslf" type comments.

Comment: Mandatory downvote comments will not be implemented because voting should be anonymous. But I'm afraid your case is an edge case. Active in a tag with not much activity can pose a risk. Maybe try to find another space to answer a few questions.

Comment: @ChrisF Then enable up vote alone. To register a down vote user should need more than 5000 points. Then you might fear, there is more possibility for up votes than down votes. No. Usually to put down vote mostly user don't think too much. For a up-vote, they always think twice.

Comment: @user10 The whole comments on downvotes issue has been discussed to death and is very unlikely to happen. I would not focus on that in this discussion/request if I were you.

Comment: i don't find any fault of @user10

Comment: @atur You might not be able to see all the account's activity. And with that said, he might well still have balanced on the edge after his previous ban, with the two downvotes tipping him back in.

Comment: i don't know why i am getting down votes for this post. These is been a problem for me from day one. We just discussing one issue. What about others and @Bart have you discussed up votes for all and down votes only having more than 5000 points. really hard to find this on that big [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Can you double check to see if you're _still_ banned? I don't think these questions had anything to do with it. It looks like you were banned, worked yourself out of it and were right on the edge, then another down vote or two came in on something older which put you back. You are right on the edge again, from what I can tell (moderators don't have access to that indicator)

Comment: I too don't find anything wrong in these four questions, but during the time when your ban was lifted you would have got a warning from the stackexchange team ,like " you are right on that edge of having your account blocked again and should work on your existing content before trying to post further", didn't you? and did you work on your previous questions?

Comment: @TimPost MilkyWay. 30 minutes before my score was 396. It is now 421. Now my ban was lifted. Why should i come and cry every time here. I am sure someone who reading this post should gave some upvotes. You should surely rethink about down vote procedure.

Comment: @TimPost asking just to make it clear, hope you read this last post by user10, is there a chance to lift a ban when our question which was downvoted gets some upvotes , will the ban be lifted automatically?

Comment: Not really. You should try to improve all of your contributions so you no longer balance on the edge. @MilKyWaY The post-ban system is fully automatic. Evaluated each time you try to post afaik.

Comment: Please propose your each feature-request via different questions. Here I agree with one of your request but disagree wither others. So not able to vote.

Comment: @hims056 :) Actually i am afraid to create more posts because of "Down Vote" system.

Comment: @user10 - Don't afraid of voting on Meta. Reputation on Meta doesn't worth more. :)

Comment: @user10 I too faced such a situation and as a last try I contacted the stackexchange team via email and got rid of this. Thereafter takes proper care not to get voted down.We can't do anything else.

Comment: @MilKyWaY We can do. That's why the formed meta.stackoverflow. I benefited  a lot by stackoverflow. So i am trying giving my contribution in this way.

Comment: @user10 sorry to say, your update seems not at all practical.Setting a    threshold reputation of 5k for voting activities is not a good suggestion.Each downvotes must provide a reason also, that can be practical.

Comment: @MilKyWaY why do you think it is not practical. Simple query will do that. And those having more than 5k points, will have clear rights to down vote. Their time is valid. They don't need to waste their time by compulsory down-vote system.

Comment: @user10 That has been discussed time and time again. Please do your research. Even on Meta.

Comment: @Bart I understand your concern. But "Down Vote" and a ban due to that is really a headache. Please someone take this to relevant authorities. No more posts or comments regarding this.

Comment: @user10 Welcome to the relevant authorities. You will simply have to deal with the community discussion here. As for the implementation, that's not up to us to decide, but you cannot stop us from commenting on any aspect of your proposal. I understand the ban is annoying, but it's there for a reason. Stopping downvotes is a terrible idea. Just improve your content and you should have no problem.

Comment: @Bart ha..ha.. you misunderstood that. I meant, i don't post or comment on this again. But you make it again. I am not that rude guy. ha. :) I lost my edit link for that comment. I should request a feature for that next. ;)

Comment: Learn using "I" consistently instead of "i". Otherwise you may keep triggering the quality filter.

Comment: @user10 Ah, haha, I misread that then. But really, not allowing downvotes is a bad idea. Even for a limited range of users. Just keep contributing good material as you are doing now and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 27):

This is what happened, as far as I can tell<sup>1</sup>.

Due to a series of down voted and ultimately deleted questions, a question ban was imposed. You then effectively lifted the ban by fixing some of them, and continued to provide helpful answers. However, you were *barely* over the threshold. As in a few down votes could have probably put you back in it.

You then posted your series of self answered questions. These were rather awesome, and you did all of us a favor by sharing what you learned so future visitors don't have to work so hard to find the information. As you noted, you're working with newer emerging technologies, which means these did not get a lot of attention. Thus, you didn't receive some positive votes that would have been well earned, which would have put you much farther away from the ban. Meanwhile, a down vote or two put you back under it.

As you can see, a few votes is all it took for it to lift again. Another few good posts from you will probably keep it from ever happening again. You might be safely on the other side of it now, at least to the point where a few negative votes won't trigger it again.

I'm sorry that you had this kind of experience with the system, not many people who find themselves question banned manage to work their way out from under it. It's a necessary evil, unfortunately, or the site would literally be overrun with extremely low quality questions.

So, thanks for being awesome and sharing what you know, I don't think you'll run into this again in the future, especially given the quality of your latest work.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Moderators don't have access to the ban indicators, I'm presenting a very educated guess.</sub>

Comment: It would probably be worth the time for a developer (or someone else with access to the ban details) to verify if this was indeed the case as described. It sounds reasonable to me, but no one of us can say for sure.

Comment: @JoachimSauer To the extent possible I'm sure one will chime in. But, given that even _moderators_ don't have access to any indication to the ban status on an account, it would be at best a .. vague confirmation. And, they may send the black helicopters if they think I'm too close to figuring it out. So, if you guys don't hear from me in a while ... well ...

Comment: There is no recorded history for triggered questions bans, but from what I can see *right now*, your conclusion is fairly spot on, @TimPost.